# PostgreSQL and postGIS, JAVA

Tags: java

I'm using `PostgreSQL` and `postGIS`. when I write a query in PostgreSQL which that is:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-14 21,0 0,35 26)') AS MyCheckMark;
```

And it qive an error which is:

```
ERROR:  function st_geomfromtext(unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-14 21,0 0,35 26)') AS My...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Error:

```
ERROR: function st_geomfromtext(unknown) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 8
```

---

How can I fix that??
Regard

Comment: Did you `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`?

Comment: I just create EXTENSION postgis ,so fixed. TNX